# How i can add auto texture coordinates in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

i created bezier surface in OpenGL this way:

```
GLfloat punktyWSP[5][5][3] = { 
    { {0,0,4}, {1,0,4},{2,0,4},{3,0,4},{4,1,4}},   
    { {0,0,3}, {1,1,3},{2,1,3},{3,1,3},{4,1,3} },
    { {0,1,2}, {1,2,2},{2,6,2},{3,2,2},{4,1,2} },
    { {0,0,1}, {1,1,1},{2,1,1},{3,1,1},{4,1,1} },
    { {0,0,0}, {1,0,0},{2,0,0},{3,0,0},{4,1,0} }
    }; 
glMap2f(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 0, 1, 15, 5, &punktyWSP[0][0][0]);
glEnable(GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3);
glMapGrid2f(u, 0, 1, v, 0, 1);
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT); 
glEnable (GL_AUTO_NORMAL);
glEvalMesh2(GL_FILL, 0, u, 0, v);
```

Now i want to texture it.
Is there any way to add **auto texture coordinates** to my surface as it it with norms and `glenable(gl_auto_normal)`? 
If there is no such a function, do you have any idea how to add coordinates to my surface? Maybe `glEnable(GL_MAP2_TEXTURE_COORD_2)` ?

Comment: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_*)`?  Specially-crafted shader?

Comment: Thanks it worked with  `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);` and `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);` but textures are very streched [link]http://i.imgur.com/HwLNBFE.png

Comment: I think i need to work on my texturing mode and way of applying textures.
Now my settings are:
`glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);`
`glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);`

Comment: For the records: You should try to avoid such an ancient OpenGL version and stick to > 3.3 Core Profile.

Comment: Man...Are you seriously using this stone age GL API in the year 2016?

Comment: @Michael Ivanov  My University REQUIRES  that from me, it's not my choice :/